# 'Conda list' shows folium is installed, but cannot "import folium" (anaconda x64)

Tags: python, anaconda, folium

I have installed folium using command 'conda install -c ioos folium=0.2.0'

It looks to have installed correctly, and it showing on 'conda list' results.

When I run python from cmdline, then attempt an import of folium, i get the following error:

```
>>>import folium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'folium'
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? If you installed folium on python2 and you're trying to import in python3, it will not work

Comment: Doh! Yes, that was the problem. I had a bit of a mess between native install of python 2 and 3 and anaconda. Cleaned everything up, and works find now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. If you are using **Anaconda**:

When you install using `conda install -c conda-forge folium`, the package will be placed in:

```
./anaconda3/envs/[name env]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium
```

When you install using pip (with an anaconda env activated), `pip install folium`, the package will be placed in:

```
./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/folium
```

Python uses **first** the sites-packages as the target directory of manually built Python packages. When you build and install Python packages from source (using distutils, probably by executing `python setup.py install`), you will find the installed modules in site-packages by default.

In this case you have two places: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` and `/anaconda3/envs/[name env]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

First the modules will be available as default in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`. Sometimes (and I really don't know why) the modules inside sites-packages conda env are not available to import automatically without export the PATH.

So, to solve this issue, you have 2 options:

- Installing using `pip install folium` and `import folium` (don't need install by `conda install`), or
- After `conda install <package>`, run `conda init`, close the terminal and open a new one. Then, try to import again.

[Here are](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) some tips about how to use pip in a conda-environment.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the `...../python3.x/site-packages` is listed within sys.path. If not append it with `sys.path.append('.....python3.8/site-packages')`